# I can receive notification from firebase cloud messaging, but how can I display on user interface

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG,"FROM:"+remoteMessage.getFrom());

    //check if the message contains data
    if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
        Log.d(TAG,"Message data:"+remoteMessage.getData());

        //check if the message contains notification
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Message body:"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }
    }
}
```

private void sendNotification(String body) {

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0/*request code*/,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    //set sound notification
    Uri notifictaionSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Cloud Messaging")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notifictaionSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0/*ID of notification*/,notifiBuilder.build());
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent=getIntent();

    if(intent !=null){
        String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");
        text.setText(message);

    }
    Button btnShowToken=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_show_token);
    btnShowToken.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.d(TAG, "Token:"+token);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: what you want exatly create the notification? explain better what you want

Comment: I mean after I receive the notification and I want the message of notification to be displayed on UI

Comment: post `sendNotification()` code

Comment: I am a newbie of Android and I hope you can be as detailed as possible  :)

Answer (score 0):

So you can try this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("message",body);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0/*request code*/,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    //set sound notification
    Uri notifictaionSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Cloud Messaging")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notifictaionSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0/*ID of notification*/,notifiBuilder.build());
```

And inside MainActivity `onCreate()` method do this:

```
Strng message=getIntent().getStringExtra("message");

if(message !=null){
  //Create ui
}
```

So I don't know the ui that you want but this gets the message from notification you only need to create ui inside activity.

**Explanation**:

This creates an intent with an string extra, in your case body, then sets intent as pendingIntent of notification.
When users clicks in notification the app open and checks if user launched by clicking in notification, if yes gets the extra that you set in intent and creates the ui, if not do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your advise but my app cant be open after modification.

Comment: I added [TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);] to Oncreate(). my app is working but the message of notification can not display on the UI

Comment: you have setText to he textview?